# Can I make the SQL font bigger in the sakila demo database (phpmyadmin)?

Tags: phpmyadmin

If I download the sakila demo database and look at it in phpmyadmin, I can adjust the font size of the SQL through Appearance Settings or by changing the theme files. Does anyone know if it is possible to increase the size of the SQL in the hosted demo database (https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/master-config/index.php?route=/database/sql&db=sakila)?

Comment: Pretty sure they don't allow manally theme per user in that demo.. Use browser zooming instead? more or less press ctrl + scroll up with the mousewheel  or `ctrl +` ?

Comment: Thanks, yes I am using browser zooming but it's not a great end result. The surrounding text is still too big relative to the SQL. I know a per-user theme is unlikely but there are three themes I can pick from in Appearance Settings (metro, original, pmahomme). I wonder if a fourth can be added, "largeSQL"? I cannot be the only person to find the SQL text really small